# List of published post dates only outputting one date

Tags: posts, loop

I have the following, which works, but only returns a single post date:

```php
function test() {
    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => 'post', 'post_status' => 'publish' );
    $posts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        $testlist = '{date: "' . get_the_date( 'Y-n-j' ) . '", value: "1"},';
    }
    echo '
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var massive = [
            ' . $testlist . '
        ];
    });
    </script>';
}
```

I'm trying to return all published post dates for the past year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are overwriting the `$testlist` variable in each iteration of the loop. You need to concatenate each date to $testlist instead.

please try to fetch all posts from the past year and create a js array containing their dates and make sure to call the test() function where you want this script to be executed

```
function test() {
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'date_query'     => array(
            'after' => '1 year ago',
        ),
    );
    $posts = get_posts( $args );
    $testlist = ''; // Initialize the variable
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        $testlist .= '{date: "' . get_the_date( 'Y-n-j', $post ) . '", value: "1"},'; // Concatenate dates
    }
    echo '
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var massive = [
            ' . $testlist . '
        ];
    });
    </script>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable $testlist is overwriting it self instead of concatenation, here's the improved code;

```
function test() {
    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => 'post', 'post_status' => 'publish' );
    $posts = get_posts( $args );
    $testlist = '';
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        $testlist .= '{date: "' . date( 'Y-n-j', strtotime( $post->post_date ) ) . '", value: "1"},';
    }
    echo '
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var massive = [
            ' . $testlist . '
        ];
    });
    </script>';
}
```

Comment: It's now correctly outputting as many dates as there are posts, but it's just duplicating the same date for all of them (they're not published on the same date to be clear). Also, is there a simple way to incorporate `date_query` to only show `-1 year` posts?

Comment: I've improved the code for date of current post type, but if you want too logical query (from date to to date) go for WP_Query.